# Can't add anonymous access to a list

Tags: list, permissions

I have a list in a Site Collection that isn't allowing me to check any boxes in the anonymous access settings window. The Site Collection is already set for anonymous access (entire site) and i have another list in the site that does work for anonymous, but this one in particular doesn't.

I noticed on a website earlier that it mentioned that lists with workflows attached wouldnt allow anonymous access (i think but i didnt catch the full description). At one point i did have a very simple, 1 step workflow attached but i have since removed it.

Any idea whats going on?

Comment: Is there any item level permissions set on this list?

Answer (score 0):

Check the List settings under Advanced Settings – Item Level Permissions – Read Access.

If the `Read Items that were created by the user option` is selected, the anonymous access cannot be activated.